# Add extension to incomplete files inside torrents

Tags: linux, bittorrent, utorrent, headless, rtorrent

uTorrent has an "Append `.!ut` to incomplete files" option:

[image]

I want to achieve something similar in rtorrent (the storage is formatted as NTFS).

I know it accepts scripting commands but the [documentation](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/RtorrentScripting) is confusing and largerly incomplete.

Comment: Implement the feature as a user or implement the feature as a developer?

Comment: @Ramhound as a user.

Comment: That functionality comes with code behind it.  If there is not code behind `rtorrent` does not exist then it cannot be enabled.  The fact there is not user option to enable it is an indication there isn't any code behind it.  Additionally the functionality is done with more then just what can be done with scripting.

Comment: Most people overcome this issue with folders and then use the plug ins to move after completion.